# User another class function in another class function

Tags: php

How to call class function in another class function

```
    class abc{

function comsumeBudget($vendor_id){
        global $db;
        global $label_obj;




        $query      =   "SELECT * from table";
        $results    =   $db->query($query) or die($db->error);

        foreach($results as $result){
                $amount = $result['amount'];
                $monthly_budget = $result['monthly_budget'];
        }
    }


    // Calculate Monthly Budget Comsumed in percentage
    if(!empty($monthly_budget)){
        $consumed_step1 =   $monthly_budget - $amount;

        $consumed_step2 =   ($consumed_step1 / $monthly_budget) * 100;

        $this->consumed =   100 - $consumed_step2;
    }else{
        $this->consumed =   0;
    }
   }
}
```

`comsumeBudget($vendor_id)` function want to call  another class function given blow

```
class def{
    function auto_suggestion_vendor($specialty, $number_providers, $state, $module, $time_frame, 
     $lead_id){
  want to call comsumeBudget($vendor_id) here
  }
```

trying to call function

Answer (score 1):

Import abc class in def class by using include or require.
Create an object of abc in def, you can create it inside the targeted function, then call the method of abc by using created object.

```
include "abc.php";
class def
{
     public function myfunction(//params)
     {
           $obj = new abc();
           $obj->functionName(//param);
     }
}
```

Comment: but when i include class file i get php error

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare time_elapsed_string() (previously declared in

Comment: do you have tow functions with the same name in both files?

Comment: So what is time_elapsed_string() function doing here?